# Combobox action get's called when programmatically clearing selection

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using this piece of code to try and remove the item that get's selected from a combobox and I want to do something further with it, but the problem is that the value selected should be removed from the list. The following is what I am using to fill the dropdown

```java
            unpickedRoles = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            rollenDropdown.setItems(unpickedRoles);
            
            unpickedRoles.addAll(Rol.DIRECTIE, Rol.MANAGER, Rol.MVOC, Rol.STAKEHOLDER);
```

```java
    @FXML
    private void selectRol(ActionEvent event) {
        Rol selected = rollenDropdown.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selected != null) {
            rollenDropdown.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            rollenDropdown.getItems().remove(selected);
        }
    }
```

Now whenever the code get's called when a selection is made apart from the first one, the code seems to get's recalled internally by the `rollenDropdown.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();` function, how could I remove the selection without the javafx action getting recalled? And how come this only happens when not selecting the first one?

EDIT: It probably has something to do with an item getting deselected thus recalling the method

EDIT 2: Adding a null check does not help

Kind regards
Jasper

Comment: I have not tested anything but I am curious. What happens if you do not use `rollenDropdown.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();`?

Comment: Ill try rught now, but I've already done that and alot of more weird things happen

Comment: So If I don't call that, the list instantly gets emptied and I get an IndexOutOfBounds. Works perfectly if I select them 1 by 1 though (only the last selected gives an error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about the unspecified time at which Platform.runLater executes the action, you can try the below approach.

This approach is effectively using the [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) to run the desired actions at the end of the current pulse.

Considering its possible performance issues (mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)),I would prefer to use Platform.runLater only in multi threading situations.

```
@FXML
private void selectRol(ActionEvent event) {
    Rol selected = rollenDropdown.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    if (selected != null) {
        doEndOfPulse(() -> {
            rollenDropdown.setValue(null);
            rollenDropdown.getItems().remove(selected);
        });
    }
}

/**
 * Executes the provided runnable at the end of the current pulse.
 *
 * @param runnable runnable to execute
 */
public static void doEndOfPulse(final Runnable runnable) {
    new AnimationTimer() {

        @Override
        public void handle(final long now) {
            runnable.run();
            stop();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [How to remove selected elements from a ComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56834141/how-to-remove-selected-elements-from-a-combobox) I had to use `Platform.runLater()` in order to make sure that the property change is dealt with before doing anything with the selection. This is the working code:

```java
    @FXML
    private void selectRol(ActionEvent event) {
        Rol selected = rollenDropdown.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        if (selected != null) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                rollenDropdown.setValue(null);
                rollenDropdown.getItems().remove(selected);
            });
        }
    }
```